# How do I enforce line-encoding at repository level

Tags: git

I have git repository hosted by SCM provider. It consists of source files for building a go application. Yaml/md files for documentation & CI pipelines

Is there a way to enforce line-ending/encoding for all contributors that create PR's against my default branch?

It should override the user settings and use what I have set in my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [.gitattributes](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file to your repository and specify in it line ending rules:

```
*.go text eol=crlf
```

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings) some github documentation about that.

Comment: Can't I enforce it for all files?

Comment: The first column in the file is the file pattern. Just use `*`

Comment: Thanks folks I'll use `* text=auto eol=lf`

Comment: @user89978 don't forget to run the command to enforce eol in working directory provided in the link (and commit the changes)